# Access apache2 sites located in /var/www/xxxxx and /var/www/html/yyyyy

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I've got a server (ubuntu 18.04) running behind the router which I'm using for testing of various web applications (snipe-it, phpipam, and libre speedtest).  Not having the resources for individual machines to run them on and not really wanting to delve into virtual machines I thought I could run them on the same instance of apache and access them by changing the virtual host configurations.

When I run individual virtual hosts each site runs fine.  when I try to run more than one site (a2ensite xxx and a2ensite yyy) the site with the lower alphabetical name (xxx in this case) shows up.

I don't know if Alias or Rewrite is the way to go.  I can't really change how the developers choose to write the apps and where they want to put their programs.  I can understand why (I think) they put them there. I just want to be able to access all of the sites/pages/apps...

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/snipeit.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName snipeit
    DocumentRoot /var/www/snipe-it/public
    Alias "/" "/var/www/snipe-it/public"
    <Directory /var/www/snipe-it/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/phpipam.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpipam
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpipam
    <Directory /var/www/phpipam>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/speedtest.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName speedtest
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/speedtest>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you accessing the site from localhost?

Comment: I'm accessing the sites from the same subnet behind the router but not localhost. server 192.168.0.250, accessing from desktop at 192.168.0.3.

Comment: Are you having different ip addresses for each one?

Comment: Same IP address 192.168.0.250.   I would like to be able to access them like this: 192.168.0.250\snipeit or 192.168.0.250\phpipam or 192.168.0.250\speedtest      I need to test the solution below but haven't had the chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to check where the issue is.

1) Check if you /etc/hosts file have the proper DNS entries for the ServerNAMe

```
snipeit.x localhost
phpipam.x localhost
speedtest.x localhost
```

2) Make sure the ServerName Directive matches with the host. ServerName should be exactly the same as the DNS name you are using to access it.

3) Check Apache VirtualHost configurations

```
apache2ctl -S
```

3) Run Apache in debug mode. and check how apache is parsing your request.

```
apache2ctl -t -c /path/to/apache.conf
```

Comment: I tried this and it still defaults to phpipam which is what apache2ctl -S shows as the default site.  It never gets to snipeit

Comment: I'm begining to think it might have something to do with either ReWrite or some form of redirection.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you might need to do this:
Move both of the directories to /var/www/html. and remove all the virtualhosts for them **except** the one for /var/www/html which is 000-default.conf. It is going to be complicated when you store them in different directories instead of this easy trick.

Edit:

The user had applications that are dependent on those paths. So the best way to do this is by using Aliases in Apache. Make sure that mod_alias is loaded in Apache. Add this to the end of httpd.conf.

```
Alias "/snipeit" "/var/www/snipe-it/public"
Alias "/phpipam" "/var/www/phpiam"
#And, speedtest is already inside the folder.
```

You can access those sites like: http://localhost/snipeit, http://localhost/phpiam, http://localhost/speedtest. Or you may use the IP Address to access it.

Comment: I tried this. I can see the directories under _html_ and click on them but the programs as written (not by me) blow up; expect the directory to be under _/var/www_ .  I don't want to have to go into the program and do the modifications if I don't have to as this will mess up upgrade process and maybe security.

Comment: Ok, so I will provide another way, but it is complicated.

Comment: @RSchnell Updated my answer